# How can I disable focus in slick slider

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

How can I disable focus in slick slider when I click in slider or control button slider was focused in center monitor and when I scroll page after some time page  back to slider. I tried `focusOnSelect: false` it's not working.

```js
$(".page-work article .field-name-field-image-p .field-items").slick({
    /*  adaptiveHeight: true, */
    autoplay: false,
    arrows: true,
    focusOnSelect: false,
    dots: true,
});
```

Comment: Choose the answer that solves your problem, please

Answer (score 13):

Try this:

```js
$('.your-class').slick({
    accessibility: false,
});
```

The cause:

https://github.com/kenwheeler/slick/blob/1.8.0/slick/slick.js#L1703

Answer (score -3):

try making centerMode: false

Reference from http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/

Comment: Thanks, pagination ceased to focus , but when I nazhymayu key focus still remained ...